# What is the right way to import certificates in AWS ACM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-certificate-manager

> I'm an absolute beginner in AWS space. I'm trying to map [serverless lambda functions to the custom domain](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-api-gateway-domain/). This is the ultimate goal!

I got a free SSL certificate from [sslforfree](https://www.sslforfree.com/) which I wish to register at AWS' ACM. Also, I do not wish to transfer domain to AWS Route 53 as GoDaddy's customer support is awesome!

I have (probably) imported the certificates [in the `ap-south-1` region](https://ap-south-1.console.aws.amazon.com/acm/home?region=ap-south-1#/importwizard/)

[image: certificate import]

Not sure if the certificate was imported? I did this multiple times - not sure how many times.

The limit seems breached - I think it's stupid for AWS systems to have the limit set to zero?

Basis this logic - assuming that the certificate was imported.

Also, I cannot see a place in the ACM console to view the imported certificates.

I found that all the assumptions were wrong.

[image: no cert found]

I tried requesting a new certificate through both DNS and Email validation approaches but I found this:

[image: request certificate error]

Using [serverless with `serverless-domain-manager` plugin](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-api-gateway-domain/)

```
sls create_domain
```

Which throws this:

```
Error --------------------------------------------------

Error: Error: Could not find the certificate ...
      at ServerlessCustomDomain.<anonymous>
```

All confirming that the certificate was not imported.

What is the right way to import certificates in AWS ACM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the initial limit set by AWS was zero. This doesn't sound sensible!

I contacted their support and increased the limit!

Now the import is done successfully!

[image: import is done successfully]