# How to connect serverless lambda functions to custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-lambda, serverless

I generated a free ssl certificate from [sslforfree](https://www.sslforfree.com/) to host my lambda functions to [api.ansaar.in](https://api.ansaar.in/) whose DNS is managed by GoDaddy.

I have a [serverless](https://serverless.com/) AWS Lambda APIs project. I intend to deploy it on a custom domain.

The custom domain's [SSL certificates were imported successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58772711/2404470).

As suggested by [serverless blog](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-api-gateway-domain/) successfully ran `sls create_domain`

[image: sls create_domain]

`sls deploy` run seems successfully too:

[image: serverless deploy]

Now, whenever I hit [api.ansaar.in](https://api.ansaar.in/) - it doesn't work at all.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a hosted zone and then create the following record set:

**Canonical Name record (CNAME Record)**

**Update**

> **Address Mapping record (A Record)**—also known as a DNS host record,
>   stores a hostname and its corresponding IPv4 address.
>
> **IP Version 6 Address record (AAAA Record)**—stores a hostname and its corresponding
>   IPv6 address.
>
> **Canonical Name record (CNAME Record)**—can be used to
>   alias a hostname to another hostname. When a DNS client requests a
>   record that contains a CNAME, which points to another hostname, the
>   DNS resolution process is repeated with the new hostname.

Source: [Here](https://ns1.com/resources/dns-types-records-servers-and-queries)

Comment: Sounds sensible. Can you please elaborate?